# python - Using argparse, pass an arbitrary string as an argument to be used in the script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

**How do I define an arbitrary string as an optional argument using argparse?**

**Example:**

```
[user@host]$ ./script.py FOOBAR -a -b
Running "script.py"...
You set the option "-a"
You set the option "-b"
You passed the string "FOOBAR"
```

Ideally, I'd like the position of the arguments to not matter. i.e:

`./script.py -a FOOBAR -b` == `./script.py -a -b FOOBAR` == `./script.py FOOBAR -a -b`

---

In BASH, I can accomplish this while using `getopts`. After handling all desired switches in a case loop, I'd have a line that reads `shift $((OPTIND-1))`, and from there I can access all remaining arguments using the standard `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc...

Does something like that exisit for argparse?

Comment: Did you go through the argparse tutorial?  Everything you are describing is there

Comment: The only part not discussed iirc is the `nargs="*"` behavior (so that one positional argument can grab all of the remaining arguments)

Comment: @Nirk, The tricky thing is that if you just use `parse_args`, as soon as it sees a "positional" argument, it stops looking for the other arguments and gathers the arguments from the positional argument to the end.  This is fine in most cases, but would break his 1st and 3rd example.

Comment: @Nirk Also, this passed string should be optional. If I do a vanilla `add_argument("word")`, it becomes mandatory.

Comment: It looks like argparse doesn't natively handle **optional** arbitrary arguments. Using @jedwards answer, I can get the desired functionality except that that arbitrary string is unknown to argparse, thus the ability to use an arbitrary string is unknown to users who invoke the `help` dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get exactly what you're looking for, the trick is to use `parse_known_args()` instead of `parse_args()`:

```
#!/bin/env python 

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-b', action="store_true")

opts = parser.parse_known_args()
# Print info about flags
if opts[0].a: print('You set the option "-a"')
if opts[0].b: print('You set the option "-b"')
# Collect remainder (opts[1] is a list (possibly empty) of all remaining args)
if opts[1]: print('You passed the strings %s' % opts[1])
```

EDIT:

The above code displays the following help information:

```
./clargs.py  -h

usage: clargs_old.py [-h] [-a] [-b]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a
  -b
```

If you want to inform the user about the optional arbitrary argument, the only solution I can think of is to subclass ArgumentParser and write it in yourself.

For example:

```
#!/bin/env python 

import os
import argparse

class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def format_help(self):
        help = super(MyParser, self).format_help()
        helplines = help.splitlines()
        helplines[0] += ' [FOO]'
        helplines.append('  FOO         some description of FOO')
        helplines.append('')    # Just a trick to force a linesep at the end
        return os.linesep.join(helplines)

parser = MyParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-b', action="store_true")

opts = parser.parse_known_args()
# Print info about flags
if opts[0].a: print('You set the option "-a"')
if opts[0].b: print('You set the option "-b"')
# Collect remainder
if opts[1]: print('You passed the strings %s' % opts[1])
```

Which displays the following help information:

```
./clargs.py -h

usage: clargs.py [-h] [-a] [-b] [FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a
  -b
  FOO         some description of FOO
```

Note the addition of the `[FOO]` in the "usage" line and the `FOO` in the help under "optional arguments".

Comment: This is good, except that I lose the built-in help dialog from argparse for the optional string.

Comment: This is true.  The only solution I can think of is to subclass ArgumentParser and write it in yourself.  Note that the only reason you have to jump through this hoop is because you want any ordering of the arguments to work.  I'll edit my answer with an example of subclassing ArgumentParser.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It seems strange that there isn't an option in argparse to have an optional argument be an arbitrary string... oh well. Thank you very much for this answer.